# Apache returns 404 on folder with non-ascii characters

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, php7

When trying to access images that are in folders that contains non-ascii characters, server returns with 404.

Weird thing is that if I do:

```
mv /path/to/dir/ščž /path/to/dir/scz
```

and then do reverse thing:

```
mv /path/to/dir/scz /path/to/dir/ščž
```

It's not longer 404 and the server sends correct image. Any ideas why that?
If it helps, permissions are 755 and user is apache:apche

Comment: I do not have experience with this problem, but it is probably an issue of character encoding and the extended characters not translating correctly. You reference php so I assume people are uploading these files, which may have a different character set from what is being used in the URL.

Comment: You are correct, people are uploading those folders. Any idea how those can be fixed?

Comment: I don't have a specific answer for you, but I would suggest figuring out what encoding is used in the URL and then converting the character set to match that for the uploaded files.  https://www.google.com/search?q=php+change+character+encoding